# Implementing an abstract method which is itself an implementation of a generic interface method

Tags: c#, interface, abstract-class, deep-copy

I get compile errors with this overcomplicated class hierarchy.  I wonder if it has anything to do with trying to do DeepCopy() with generics mixed in.

```
public interface IInterface<T>
{
    IInterface<T> DeepCopy();
}

public abstract class AbstractClass<T> : IInterface<T>
{
    public abstract IInterface<T> DeepCopy(); // Compiler requires me to declare this public
}

// Everything good at this point.  There be monsters below

public class ConcreteClass: AbstractClass<SomeOtherClass>
{
    ConcreteClass IInterface<SomeOtherClass>.DeepCopy()
    {
        return new ConcreteClass;
    }
}
```

I get the following compiler errors:

```
'IInterface<...>.DeepCopy()': containing type does not implement interface 'IInterface<SomeOtherClass>'
```

Comment: What happens when you remove the explicit Interface prefix for `MyMethod`?

Comment: Edited the question to change MyMethod to DeepCopy (as it actually is in my workspace. I suck at anonymizing).  Removing the explicit Interface prefix results in a compiler error saying I should implement AbstractClass<SomeOtherClass>.DeepCopy()

Comment: You're missing aclass keyword, should be `public abstract class AbstractClass<T>`

Comment: You guys have compilers in your heads! And I need caffeine in mine...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return bool

Change <strike>`ConcreteClass IInterface<SomeOtherClass>.MyMethod()`</strike>
to `bool IInterface<SomeOtherClass>.MyMethod()`

**Edit:**
And then you can not use an explicit implementation of the interface, since that does not fulfill the contract of the abstract class you need to implement it like this.

```
public override IInterface<SomeOtherClass> DeepCopy()
{
    return new ConcreteClass();
}
```

Comment: Damn, made a mistake sanitizing the code.  Updating my question.

Comment: @Jeremy, I updated my answer with how and why you need to change your ConcreteClass.

Comment: You got it.  Nailed it through trial and error myself as well.

Answer (score 2):

The errors are because the return type of `DeepCopy()` do not match the declaration in the interface.

Besides that you have a different problem. The abstract class already implements the method from the interface, but in the concrete class you do not implement the abstract method. Instead of the implementation you now have, you should have the following implementation:

```
public override IInterface<SomeOtherClass> DeepCopy()
{
}
```

This will implement the abstract method in the abstract class which automatically implements the method in the interface. The reason you need to implement the abstract method in the abstract class, is because that class needs to implement the interface. That is a requirement of a class.

Comment: Damn, made a mistake sanitizing the code. Updating my question

Comment: The updated question does not make any sense. The interface does not have a method `MyMethod` and with the explicit implementation (the `IInterface<...>.` before the method) implements a method that does not exist. Could you please check again?

Comment: Apologies sir, I meant to make all methods DeepCopy.  Updated it again.

Comment: The answer does not change. Your problem still is that your return types do not match. I've updated my answer with the correct definitions.

Comment: I understand.  I take it that the override keyword is necessary to indicate that the ConcreteClass.DeepCopy() targets the AbstractClass.DeepCopy() implementation, right? I tried dropping that and it resulted in the message that "ConcreteClass does not implement inherited abstract member AbstractClass.DeepCopy()".